# know the file type with google-apps-script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to get the type of file.
When I use getFileType() function I only get "other" as described here :  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_docslist_filetype
So how can I really know the type ? (pdf,jpg)

Answer (score 8):

You can get the MIME Type which can give you better idea of the Google Doc Format. Here's the sample

```
DriveApp.getFileById(id).getMimeType()
```

Answer (score 3):

`File.getBlob().getContentType()` should help although I agree that there should be an easier solution.

Answer (score 0):

Some string manipulation:

`getContentType` will return a Google Doc's type. If the type is other, then get the file's complete name. Find the last "." in the file name and then get the substring starting after this period.

This gets you the document type if it's a Google Docs/Sheets/Slides and the file extension if it's something else.